# Using Javascript search an email for txt then take the string after into variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write code to search the following and find "Office Location:" and then take whatever the string after it is into a variable, in this case UK-London I write some basic code to find Office Location but don't know how to select the string after.  I think this is something simple and I am an idiot (hopefully because I am still new to this) Thanks!
-Alex

Employee Name: Joe Blow 
Employee ID: 17811 
Hire Date: 07/21/2014 
Employee Type: Regular 
Job Title: ATE-0016 - Claims Adjuster 
Manager: His boss 
Office Location: UK-London 
Department: CLM-Administration 
Cost Center: 03-3002 AEL & AMSL: Claims 
 [not available]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try posting some of your code so we can see where best to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should find the Office Location as long as the text 'Office Location' doesn't appear anywhere else in the text.

```
var officeLocation = /Office Location: (.+)/.exec(emailContent)[1];
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xuFGh/)

Comment: Thanks, that did it, almost... it also seemed to take in some extra text after UK-London in the  officeLocation variable  `<BR><BR><br>Department:`

Comment: Nevermind I was messing with it, it works great. I figured it was some kindergarten code.